# SFML not moving sprites correctly

Tags: c++, sfml

SFML is not moving the sprites more than 1 pixel (even if held). It also moves the sprite back to its set position upon release of the arrow key that is being held down.

```
void Engine::mainLoop() {
     //Loop until window is closed
     while (window->isOpen()) {
          processInput();
          update();
          sf::Sprite test;
          sf::Texture texTest;
          texTest.loadFromFile("img.png");
          test.setTexture(texTest);
          test.setPosition(50, 50);
          if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Up))
               test.move(0, -1);
          if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Down))
               test.move(0, 1);
          if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Left))
               test.move(-1, 0);
          if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Right))
               test.move(1, 0);
          window->clear(sf::Color::Black);
          window->draw(test);
          renderFrame();
          window->display();
     }
}
```

Comment: you are always calling `setPosition` so it'll always be around 50, 50 +-1

Comment: I feel very stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of the comment mentioning that you always set the position, you're also recreating the sprite each frame, so it's position will always be reset even without you calling `setPosition`

As a side note, you're also loading the texture every frame, which is very inefficient!

This should be what you're after:

```
void Engine::mainLoop() {
  sf::Sprite test;
  sf::Texture texTest;
  texTest.loadFromFile("img.png");
  test.setTexture(texTest);
  test.setPosition(50, 50);

 //Loop until window is closed
 while (window->isOpen()) {
      processInput();
      update();
      if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Up))
           test.move(0, -1);
      if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Down))
           test.move(0, 1);
      if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Left))
           test.move(-1, 0);
      if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Right))
           test.move(1, 0);
      window->clear(sf::Color::Black);
      window->draw(test);
      renderFrame();
      window->display();
 }
}
```